# What NSTextFieldDelegate trully is?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols, grammar

The declaration of **NSTextFieldDelegate** really confuse me a lot.

In Xcode, I click "jump to defination" of NSTextFieldDelegate, and found:

```
@protocol NSTextFieldDelegate <NSControlTextEditingDelegate> @end
```

I have known that if we add a <...> syntax after a NSObject type (such as "id") declaration, that means this object comforms to the protocol specified in "<>".

However, books of Obj-C I have do not mentioned what it means when the "<>" means when it follows a protocol declaration...

So, **Question 1:** What does "<>" means when it is after a declaration of protocol?

---

I continued look into the *NSControlTextEditingDelegate*, and found several methods begin with "control:...". But what attracted me most was the text above the *NSControlTextEditingDelegate* defination:

```
@interface NSObject(NSControlSubclassNotifications)

- (void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)obj;
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj;
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj;

@end
```

Oh, here comes new questions:
**Question 2:** What is the syntex "NSObject(NSControlSubclassNotifications)" means? What is *NSControlSubclassNotifications* actually?

**Quesiont 3:** What are the relationships among NSObject, NSControlSubclassNotifications and NSControlTextEditingDelegate? The apple doc simply says: "The NSTextFieldDelegate protocol adopts the NSControlTextEditingDelegate protocol and currently does not extend it further." But I could not understand its meaning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means that the protocol conforms to ("adopts") another protocol, so basically the protocol contains all the methods in both protocols. It's somewhat similar to subclassing.
2. It's a category, in this case used as an informal protocol. It fulfills pretty much the same purpose as a (formal) protocol here (though that's just one use case of categories), you'll mostly see this style in older APIs.
3. `NSControlSubclassNotification` is a category on `NSObject`. It basically adds new methods to all classes that inherit from `NSObject`. `NSTextFieldDelegate` is effectively the same as `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`, just with a different name, but it's possible that new methods might be added to it in the future that are unrelated to `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`, so that's probably why it's designed as a separate protocol.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand Q1 and 2! But for 3, I still have some confusions. In the .h file, the "controlTextDidChange:" and other similar methods are declared in a category. It seems not to be related to "NSTextFieldDelegate" (because I did not find the defination of it). But why auto-sompletion shows the "controlTextDid..." methods when we declare that a object conforms to NSTextFieldDelegate? Where is its defination?

Comment: `controlTextDidChange:` will show up in auto-completion for pretty much any object, no matter if it conforms to `NSTextFieldDelegate` or not. It's defined in a category on `NSObject`, which means that it's added to that class (and any subclasses thereof).

Comment: Oh, now I understand that. Thank you!